# Function to reverse the bits of the hex number in decimal and return hex value of the reversed bits

Tags: c++, c

Given hex number 0x1234 passed as parameter to function I trying to write the function that will reverse the bit of the number and return that reversed number 0x2C48
I can explain the solution which I am trying to reach.
0x1234 this is the input hex number which will be given to the function
0x2C48 will be the output which I want to achieve.

4 (in binary)==> 0100; (rev_bits)==> 0010 ==>2

3 (in binary)==> 0011; (rev_bits)==> 1100 ==>C

2 (in binary)==> 0010; (rev_bits)==> 0100 ==>4

1 (in binary)==> 0001; (rev_bits)==> 1000 ==>8

Comment: What is your question about this work?

Comment: Where is your code? Do we neet to write it for you?

Comment: actually i am trying to code but not getting the logic

Comment: Please help I am complete novice in this and I want to learn.

Comment: Simplest is to split the number into digits and look each one up in a table to get the new value.

Comment: Recommendation: Don't code until you know the logic. To figure out the logic, start with pen and paper. If you're not sure or your pen and paper implementation doesn't work, ask a targeted question about it.

Comment: Ok I am on it. Trying

Comment: Search the internet for "C++ bit twiddling".  There are already plenty of examples on the internet.

Comment: Yuor question is wrong. If you want to reverse the the nibbles the answer will be 0x84c2 (but keep the nibbles order)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many methods to do this.  Here is one using bit shifting.
Let `A` be the original value, such as `1100`.
Let `B` be the result value.

```
+---+---+---+---+    +---+---+---+---+  
| 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |    | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |  
+---+---+---+---+    +---+---+---+---+  
        A                    B
```

Step 1:  Set the least significant bit in `A` to `B`.

```
              +---------------------+  
              |                     |  
              ^                     v  
+---+---+---+---+    +---+---+---+---+  
| 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |    | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |  
+---+---+---+---+    +---+---+---+---+  
        A                    B
```

Step 2:  Shift `A` right by one bit.  Shift `B` left by one bit.

```
+---+---+---+---+    +---+---+---+---+  
| 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 |    | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |  
+---+---+---+---+    +---+---+---+---+  
        A                    B
```

Repeat 3 more times:

```
+---+---+---+---+    +---+---+---+---+  
| 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 |    | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |  
+---+---+---+---+    +---+---+---+---+  
        A                    B  

+---+---+---+---+    +---+---+---+---+  
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |    | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |  
+---+---+---+---+    +---+---+---+---+  
        A                    B  

+---+---+---+---+    +---+---+---+---+  
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |    | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 |  
+---+---+---+---+    +---+---+---+---+  
        A                    B
```

The implementation of the above algorithm is left for the OP.